# Disable view adjustment while presenting keyboard in UIModalPresentationFormSheet ipad landscape orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, landscape

As per apple documentation on UIModalPresentationFormSheet of UIViewController; 
**If the device is in a landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the view is adjusted upward so the view remains visible.**

Is there is any way to disable this adjustment ? I don't want this to be happen in my case. I need my own adjustment in this case.

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same question. If I could find out what the adjustment IS that would be helpful; if not, I would need to create my own as well. Were you able to find an answer to your question?